# How do we download a file by using Selenium?

Tags: selenium

How do we download a file by using Selenium?

Comment: I answered to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11653293

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verifying file download with Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306736/verifying-file-download-with-selenium)

Answer (score 2):

Selenium doesn't recognize windows based components and hence would not interact with "Save As" dialog boxes. To do that you need to use a 3rd party tool that would handle these dialog boxes. I would suggest using AutoIt. Its a free script writing tool and will handle all the dialog boxes. For more info, visit http://qtp-help.blogspot.com/2009/07/selenium-handle-dialogs.html

Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Regards,
Vamyip

Comment: AutoIt is my tool of choice as well!  I posted example script in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827387

Comment: For X11 - (for example Linux, but no only), checkout [xdotool by Jordan Sissel](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/), cause "tool lets you simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc."