# Verifying file download with Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, gui-testing

I need to use selenium to verify a download. I need to click on the download file link and check that it is downloadable or not. (Means download is starting or not) 
I need to create a simple HTML script for this. But as Selenium does not recognize the 'Save As' dialog box for file download, I am not able to proceed.
Is there any solution within Selenium for this. I cannot use any other 3rd party tool as this is a part of centralized UI testing script. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: These should be a good read. http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/ and http://www.jsystemtest.org/?q=node/70

Answer (score 0):

My solution (in C#) is get the Url of the file to download and any cookie and make the request using WebClient:

```
        var testLink = seleniumDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Link to file"));
        var pdfHref = testLink.GetAttribute("href");
        var manage = seleniumDriver.Manage();
        var cookies = manage.Cookies.AllCookies;
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            foreach (var cookie in cookies)
            {
                var cookieText = cookie.Name + "=" + cookie.Value;
                wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookieText);
            }
            var fileResult = wc.DownloadData(new Uri(pdfHref));
            // or use wc.DownloadString or wc.DownloadFile
            // Do any test required
        }
```

Comment: Could you do the same just with Selenium IDE? (Means just JS in a the tablish html.)