# How to verify that a file has been downloaded

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing some automated tests in selenium, one thing which I would like to check is whether a file has been downloaded.

The download is initiated by navigating to a certain page (via selenium). The test needs to be carried out on a variety of machines, including Windows and Mac so  the downloads folder won't necessarily be in the same place each test run. The name of the downloaded file will start with the same character sequence, so I can regex it.

I'd like to do this in Java so that it can be from the same code as everything else.

Comment: you can´t "realy" check it unless you will search in the whole harddrive, if the download exists in there. If you have a fixed filepath, where the download goes to, you can use the `exists();` method from the `File` class

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I don't have a fixed filepath :)

Comment: so you won´t be able to handle it, if the user moved the file, or the file is damaged in some way. you would have to some things like binary comparison, for example. And in case your files are pretty large this whole stuff could slow down your application a lot. Unless u don´t know a fix path, or your harddrive isn´t bigger then a few MB, every algorythm which tries to check this would need a lot of time

Comment: Well the machines are virtual machines without actual users so user interference wouldn't be a problem. I'm pretty sure that I can't check for the file itself realistically, so might have to settle for checking the url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verifying file download with Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306736/verifying-file-download-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, I found that I couldn't reliably verify the file download, as I couldn't be sure of the download location (or even the filesystem, due to testing on different platforms). Decided in the end to check the URLs currently being accessed as the next best thing.